# Best perl method to determine if a TCP port is available

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, tcp

What is the best method using perl to determine if a tcp port is available. I want to select a port in advance of creating a network service. This is all to be done using automation and the requirement is to build a configuration for the service including an available tcp port within a range used by the service.

Possible methods under consideration:

1. IO::Socket to test bind on a candidate port.
2. Net::Telnet to test connecting to the candidate port
3. Linux::Proc::Net::TCP

What is the best method and why? I don't like the test bind very much because it requires root for privileged ports and if something goes wrong with the script it might leave all tested ports in time_wait. I like the Linux::Proc::Net::TCP because it's fast but it's not portable.

Comment: Hum... Why would a port that was never opened go into the time_wait state?

Answer (score 4):

`bind` will immediately and specifically tell you if the port is not available (`EADDRINUSE`). The other options don't make any sense.

Since it sounds like you don't actually care to what port you are bound, it seems to me that a better approach would be to `bind` to port `0`, which binds to an available port. You can determine the port to which your socket was bound using `sockaddr_in`.

If, on the other hand, the desired port is within 1..1023, then it's simply up to you to reserve the port for your program. The system won't automatically assign a service to those ports. (I'm not sure if that's true on Windows.)

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because the port must fall within a range assigned to the service. I can't just take the next available port.

Comment: Is that range within 1..1023? If so then the system won't automatically assign a service to those ports, and it's simply up to you to decide to reserve one of those ports for your program.